# Pass NSArray from self.view to subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

i want to pass NSArray from my self.view to a subview here is my code.

**mainView.h**

```
   NSArray *rssData;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *rssData;
```

**mainView.m**

```
@synthesize rssData;
MySubView *datacarry = [[MySubView alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i<rssOutputData.count; i++) {

            self.rssData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_name], @"hotelname",
                                             [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_price], @"startingfrom",
                                             [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_city],@"city",
                                             [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_distance],@"distance",
                                             [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_image],@"imagesnames",
                                             [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_stars],@"numberofstars",
                                             [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmlhotel_id],@"hotelid",
                                             @"45.5016889",@"hotelLat",
                                             @"-73.567256",@"hotelLong", nil],nil];

datacarry.rssData = self.rssData;
nslog(@"%@",datacarry.rssData); // here i can see data that is is transferred

}
```

**here is my subview which is MySubView**

**MySubView.h**

```
NSArray *rssData;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *rssData;
```

**MySubView.m**

```
@synthesize rssData;
//rssData= [[NSArray alloc] init];
nslog(@"%@",rssData); // here i can see NO DATA
```

Comment: well, you don't have to alloc init again in your mySUbView.

Comment: even then i cant nslog data in mySUbView

Comment: try strong instead of retain. And where are you doing NSLOg in mySUbView ?

Comment: i tried strong but still nslog in null. doing nslog in viewdidload of mySUbView

Comment: hide this line `rssData= [[NSArray alloc] init];` and try

Comment: Should we assume that everything you call a view is actually a view controller?

Comment: yes it is a viewcontroller

Comment: OK, how do you present an instance of `MySubView`?  I see you creating one and you say the `NSLog` is in `viewDidLoad` but I don't get how the loading is happening.  (Can you also log the values of `dataCarry` when you create it and `self` inside `viewDidLoad` to verify that they are the same object (i.e. same address)?)

Comment: when will you call  the MysubView

Comment: PLease add complete code, not just peices of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not provide an init method like `- (instancetype)initWithRssDats:(NSArray *)rssData` in `MySubView`?

MySubView.h

```
- (instancetype)initWithRssDats:(NSArray *)rssData;
```

MySubView.m

```
- (instancetype)initWithRssDats:(NSArray *)rssData {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.rssData = [rssData copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

mainView.m

```
MySubView *datacarry = [[MySubView alloc] initWithRssDats:self.rssData];
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all remove alloc init of array.
 put some more code to resolve your issue.

Comment: please view updated question